# Django - How to read JSON with angularJS?

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, json, django

I'm using AngularJS post to get JSON from a Django server: 
all goes well but when I get the response the JSON is not a "pure" JSON :

Django code:

```
def get_sim_list():
  t_sim = RD_sim_list.objects.all()
  t_list_sim = {}
  for sim in t_sim :
    t_list_sim['sim_id'] = sim.sim_id
    t_list_sim['sim_iccid'] = sim.sim_iccid
  return JsonResponse(t_list_sim, safe=False)
```

AngularJS code :

```
$http.post("./LoadJSON/", {mode:"1" ,submode:"1"})
                    .then(function(response) 
                        { 
                        var json_data = response.data;
                        for(var i=0;i < json_data.length ;i++)
                            {
                            t_list.push({
                                pk:json_data[i].sim_id,
                                sim_iccid:json_data[i].sim_iccid});
                            }
                         })
```

This code works, but when I retreive data I get this result:

```
Content-Type: application/json

{sim_id: "1", sim_iccid: "123456"}
```

Ofc I can remove the "Content-Type etc", but how to tell the server not print it?

plus: how can I parse a "non-pure" JSON data?

Thank You!

Comment: That's an HTTP header. It's not part of the content body and has no effect at all on the output.

Answer (score 0):

try `$http.post("./LoadJSON/", {"mode":"1" ,"submode":"1"})`
instead of `$http.post("./LoadJSON/", {mode:"1" ,submode:"1"})`

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to reinvent the wheel? If you have a custom made json-like fileformat then you'll have to write your own function for parsing the data.

Try this for parsing standard json:

```
var str = '{"key": "value", "key2": "value2"}';
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(str);
```

Comment: My question is: why my server print "Content-Type: application/json"?.